# How to subset a pandas timeindexed data based on a list of bespoke times?

Tags: pandas, subset

I have a dataframe that is time indexed as below:

```
date
2020-06-17 23:00:00    558
2020-06-17 23:01:00    184
2020-06-17 23:02:00    113
2020-06-17 23:03:00     85
2020-06-17 23:04:00     47
                      ... 
2020-07-01 18:48:00    203
2020-07-01 18:49:00    118
2020-07-01 18:50:00    236
2020-07-01 18:51:00    216
2020-07-01 18:52:00    198
Name: quarklgt, Length: 13478, dtype: int64
```

I have a list as :

```
tss=["12:00:04","1:00:06","2:00:10","5:00:14","9:00:24"]
```

How can i subset/filter the dataframe for only tss list please?
I tried `df.index.between_time(tss[0],len(tss)-1)` but that will give all data in between. Much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my approach, first you would need to split the datetime  objects into date and hh:mm:ss format. Afterwards, we'll transform the `hh:mm:ss` into strings, and use `.isin(tss)` as the mask for the filtering. All in all:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df = df[df['date'].map(lambda x: str(x).split()[1]).isin(tss)]
```

Here's an example, it is supposed to keep the second, fourth and sixth row:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2020-06-17 23:00:00',
                           '2020-06-17 12:00:04',
                           '2020-06-17 23:02:00',
                           '2020-06-17 1:00:06',
                           '2020-06-17 23:03:00',
                           '2020-06-17 2:00:10',
                           '2020-07-01 18:48:00',
                           '2020-07-01 18:49:00',
                           '2020-07-01 18:50:00',
                           '2020-07-01 18:51:00',
                           '2020-07-01 18:52:00']}).set_index('date')
```

After using the code:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df = df[df['date'].map(lambda x: str(x).split()[1]).isin(tss)]
```

The output is:

```
                  date
1  2020-06-17 12:00:04
3   2020-06-17 1:00:06
5   2020-06-17 2:00:10
```

Comment: Many thanks Celius. I tried that but I do not get the desired result. In fact the whole df comes out empty. Does tss need to be a Datetimeindex object? At present it is a string.

Comment: I apologise. tss did not have seconds while the df date had seconds. So it was my bad as a formatting issue. This works perfect. Many thanks Celius.

Comment: BTW, I should also mention in the passing that I tried another method using multiindex where it splits the df into two indices of date and time but then I got stuck in the subsetting process. I was not sure how to subset based on an index of a multiindex df. Anyway your method worked perfect so I will use that. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad you could make it work! Feel free to accept the answer to mark your question as solved!